Getting error status: 405 when using Options request method for specific end point(location block) in nginx config file
So, I used client_max_body_size for specific end point as some files from that that location can be larger and I got 405 error after adding location block:
location /call {
   client_max_body_size 50M;
}

However, if I remove this block, it is working very well! I need help with that.
I tried adding headers like this:
location /call {
   client_max_body_size 50M;
   proxy_pass http://nvoip-php:9000;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

Got error 502. I am expecting to get rid of error 405.
